# How to move file from one folder to different folder in linux

Tags: c, linux, mv

How to move a particular file from one folder to another folder?

What I have tried,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *tFile;
    if (tFile != NULL)
        tFile = NULL;
    if ((tFile = fopen("TempFile.txt", "rw")) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    mv("TempFile.txt", "../MST");

    printf("Done Succesfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
test.c:17:2: warning: no newline at end of file
/tmp/ccKLWYNa.o(.text+0x5e): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `mv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: HINT: `mv` is a shell command.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why “no newline at end of file” for a compilation units main file is a default-enabled warning, but “implicit declaration of function” is not.

Comment: @devnull... Can I use it in my program without creating another process?

Comment: there is `system()` to call `mv` but you should really just use `rename`

Comment: @Heather... I do not want to create another process for that.

Comment: BTW, the correct terminology on Linux and Posix is *directory* not *folder*

Comment: @JonasWielicki: please put on [GCC bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) a suggestion about such warnings.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry, I don't know whether and what is appropriate. I build my software with ``-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter`` and I think that should be the default, so I'm a bit biased ;). I cannot really imagine why people would use implicitly declared functions, but maybe there's a use for it

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but such an opinion is not enough expressed in GCC. So please fill a bugzilla!

Answer (score 12):

### You really should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

To move (from C) a file from one place to another *in the same file system* just use the [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) syscall.

At the very least, for your particular example, you'll need to code:

```
char* srcpath = "TempFile.txt"; // assume it is a variable path
char destpath[1024];
snprintf (destpath, sizeof(destpath), "../MST/%s", srcpath);
if (rename (srcpath, destpath)) {
   // something went wrong
   if (errno == EXDEV) {
      // copy data and meta data 
   } else { perror("rename"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
} 
else { // the rename succeeded
}
```

<sup>If you really want to `mv TempFile.txt ../MST/TempFile.txt` specifically for `TempFile.txt` only you could just call `rename("TempFile.txt", "../MST/TempFile.txt")` and handle the error cases like I suggest. If you are sure that `../MST/`lie in the same file system than `.` then `EXDEV` should not happen and you don't need to handle it particularly (but you do need to handle errors).</sup>

If you want to move a file between two different file systems, you have to copy the data (and perhaps some of the meta-data) yourself (and then remove e.g. with [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)) the original source file). You could detect that situation by various means: you could just try the `rename` and if `errno` (see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)) is `EXDEV` you need to copy the file. Or you could use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to query the source file(and the destination *directory*) meta-data -e.g. its size and its file system.

Of course, you need to understand what are files on Linux (or Posix), in particular what is an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).... See [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

You could have used `system` with `/bin/mv` (but be careful about strange characters -like spaces or semicolons- in the file paths, you need to escape them to avoid [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)), apparently you don't want to.

You should play with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (or perhaps also `ltrace`) on `mv` in various situations to understand what it is doing. Also, study the source code of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) which provides `/bin/mv` notably in [mv.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mv.c) ...

Some extra C or C++ libraries may provide you with functions to move files (in the same filesystem they should do a `rename`, in different file systems they copy the source file data and perhaps some meta-data and unlink the source, so cannot be atomic), e.g. in C [g_file_move](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-move) (from [Gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/) with Glib from Gnome), or in C++ [copy_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file) -followed by `remove` in Boost, etc etc....

PS. For temporary files see [tmpfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html), [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html), etc...