# Copy files out of different folders to a specific on in C++

Tags: c++, windows

My problem is that i have several folders with the names "MORE0001" "MORE0002" etc and they contain one `.SPE`-file each.

I want to know if there is a way to extract all the `.SPE`-files to ONE folder by iterating through all the single-`MORE...`-folders.

I need sth. like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++){

newfile = getfile("directory/MORE%04d/filename.SPE", i); 

// copy newfile to a new directory..

}
```

I hope you guys can help me find an easy solution, because i didn´t find a similar problem yet.

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161243/how-to-move-file-from-one-folder-to-different-folder-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it´s just TOO easy..

i can just use the rename-function..

so it would be like:

```
rename(path/filename.SPE, newpath/filename.SPE);
```

thanks, but solved it myself ;)!

Answer (score 0):

I have created one sample program, which might helps to resolve your problem.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<regex>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    regex e1("MORE\\d+");
    string szDir = "C:\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(szDir.c_str(), &ffd);
    do
    {
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (regex_match(ffd.cFileName,e1 ))
            {
                string  s1 = ffd.cFileName;
                string s2 = "C:\\" + s1 + "\\*";
                WIN32_FIND_DATA ffdMORE;
                HANDLE hFindMORE = FindFirstFile(s2.c_str(), &ffdMORE);
                do
                {
                    regex e2("\\w+.SPE");
                    if (regex_match(ffdMORE.cFileName,e2))
                    {
                        string commondir = "C:\\CommonDir\\";
                        string sourcePath = "C:\\" + s1 + "\\";
                        CopyFile(sourcePath.append(ffdMORE.cFileName).c_str(), commondir.append(ffdMORE.cFileName).c_str(), FALSE);
                    }
                } while (FindNextFile(hFindMORE, & ffdMORE) != 0);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
}
```

Thanks,
Bharathraj